# Why do my models have black fuzzy bits on them?

Tags: modeling

[image]I've been working on a hmmwv and it was going fine until this glitch randomly appeared on every object in the scene.

The 'Texture' of object mode/edit mode has black fuzzy bits in it and some of the mesh you can see through some of the mesh you can't but their is clearly a face their as when I go into face select mode I can highlight the ones I can see through. I've also tried to fix it by highlighting it and removing doubles but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I have a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like "z-fighting" -- when you have multiple polys that are overlapping (normals facing the same direction) and very close to each other... and then your camera is far away, then the renderer has a hard time figuring out which pixels of which poly to draw first, and you end up with erratic drawing that ends up looking like that.

Are you layering polys that way?

Comment: I doubt it because it was fine one minute then then the next it was all messed up and everything on the hmmwv was messed up like the picture of the wheel I sent you

Comment: there is also no problems with it in material mode here is a picture of what I'm talking about http://imgur.com/a/IZtIp

Comment: Ok its fixed I just copied everything from my scene and loaded up a new start up file and pasted everything into it :)